# Finding the angles of $\triangle ABC$, the area of $\triangle ABC$, $BC$, and $AB$

Tags: geometry

At the triangle $ABC$ is $AC = 8, B = 30^\circ$ and the length of the normal $BP$ from $B$ on the line through $AC$ is $6$, see figure.
a) Determine the angles in $ABC$.
b) Determine the area in $ABC$.
c) Determine $BC$ and $AB$

[image]

Comment: Let no one ignorant of geometry enter here!

Comment: You should post this on the math Stack Exchange site.  This site is for the software package "Mathematica".

Comment: You would learn a great deal more if you started participating in the High School Geometry sub-forum of the Art of Problem Solving.  Give it a try. :)    And it's not just for high-schoolers either.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: @Artes with the amount of reputations you acquired, maintain more humble statements - how you define ignorant? At what level someone is non-ignorant? Did you pass an IGNORANT test? Blue has 68K+ and Taussig 64.9K and both provided with REALLY VALUED response!

Comment: @Aril part of the problem is obvious, a second simple calculation, and third Pythagorean relation.

Comment: @Moti  Since you don't know what had been written above Plato's academy these words are fair also to you. I don't like this site since there are too many full of complexes. I prefer Mathematica.Stackexchenge.com

Comment: @Moti It is not so easy. If you can solve in more simple way, or even express final answer in more simple form, please show how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Solution picture]

The most simple part of problem is finding area of $ABC$: $S=AC\cdot BP/2=8\cdot 6/2=24$.

There are many possible way of solving of other parts using equations. There is also way of solving step-by-step without equations. This way is given below.

Let draw circumscribed circle of ABC wit center O. Then $\angle AOC=2\angle ABC=60°$ and $OA=OC$, therefore triangle $OAC$ is equilateral, therefore $OA=OC=OB=8$.

Let connect O with middle D of segment AC. OD is median of equilateral triangle and is perpendicular to AC. Length of OD can be found from ODA triangle: $OD=\sqrt{OA^2-DA^2}=4\sqrt{3}$.

Let draw point E on OD such that BE is perpendicular to OD. Quadrilateral BPDE is rectangle, because it has three angles of 90°. Then $ED=BP=6$. Then $OE=OD-DE=4\sqrt{3}-6$. Length of BE can be found from OEB triangle: $BE=\sqrt{OB^2-OE^2}=2\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}$. $DP=BE=2\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}$, $AP=DP-AD=2\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}-4$. Length of AB can be found from APB triangle: $AB=\sqrt{AP^2+BP^2}=4 \sqrt{3\sqrt{3}+2-\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}}$.

Length of BC can be found from area of ABC: $BC=\frac{2S}{AB\sin ABC}=\frac{24}{\sqrt{3\sqrt{3}+2-\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}}}=4 \sqrt{3\sqrt{3}+2+\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}}$.

Sine of angle ACB can be found from sine rule:
$\sin ACB=\frac{AB}{AC}\sin ABC=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3\sqrt{3}+2-\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}}$. $AB < AC$, then $\angle ACB < 30°$, then $\angle ACB=\arcsin \sin ACB=\arcsin(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3\sqrt{3}+2-\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}})$. Angle CAB can be found from sum of angles: $\angle CAB=180°-\angle ABC-\angle ACB=150°-\arcsin(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3\sqrt{3}+2-\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}})$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Ivan Kaznacheyeu!